# Konjunktiv I bei Diagrammbeschreibung?

Tags: subjunctive, grammaticality

Wenn man sich die eine oder andere Analyse einer Grafik anschaut, stößt man oft auf den Konjunktiv, z.B.

> 8 Prozent der Befragten sind der Ansicht, dass "Eher zu wenig" oder "Eindeutig zu wenig" darüber gesprochen werde.

Warum braucht man den Konjuktiv, wenn hier von indirekter Rede nicht gesprochen werden kann? Also ich gehe zumindest davon aus, dass die Befragten das nicht ausdrücklich gesagt haben, auch wenn sie diese Möglichkeit gewählt haben.

Comment: Unabhängig vom Konjunktiv, finde ich, können solche Aussagen nicht so formuliert werden. Ich denke, man kann höchstens sagen, dass 8 % der Befragten angaben, dass "Eher zu wenig" darüber gesprochen wurde oder werde oder wird. Eine Befragung kann nur schwerlich ermitteln welche Ansicht jemand hat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Konjunktiv 1 wird verwendet, um Aussagen als innerlich abhängig darzustellen. Dies ist am häufigsten — aber nicht ausschließlich — bei der indirekten Rede der Fall, wo Verben wie *sagen*, *fragen*, *meinen*, *sprechen*, *äußern* u.a. auftreten:

> Die Befragten *sagten*, es *werde* zu wenig darüber gesprochen.
>
> Die Befragten *meinten*, dass zu wenig darüber gesprochen *werde*.
>
> Die Befragten *äußerten* die Vermutung, dass zu wenig darüber gesprochen *werde*.

Aber auch bei ähnlichen Aussagen, wo diese Verben nicht auftreten, kann eine innerliche Abhängigkeit bestehen:

> Die Befragten *hoffen*, dass die Befragung bald *ende*.
>
> Die Befragten *dachten*, dass die Befragung nun zu Ende sein *müsse*.

oder, um näher bei deinem Beispiel zu bleiben,

> Die Befragten *sind der Ansicht*, dass zu wenig darüber gesprochen *werde*.

<sup>Siehe etwa http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/konjunktiv/konjunktiv.php#konjunktiv1</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Die Formulierung in deinem Beispielsatz ist falsch - Es handelt sich hier nicht um indirekte Rede, sondern um einen ganz normalen Nebensatz. Es muss heißen:

> ...sind der Ansicht, dass zu wenig darüber gesprochen wird.

"der Ansicht sein" ist wörtlich genommen keine Äußerung, sondern ein Zustand.

Es handelt sich hier möglicherweise um einen Fall von Hyperkorrektur.

Comment: Man könnte zustimmen, dass der Konjunktiv überflüssig ist, weil eben von einer bestimmten Ansicht gesprochen wird, nämlich der "Ansicht, dass zu wenig darüber gesprochen wird". Jedoch sollte man dann dringend — um die Behauptung nicht glattweg als richtig hinzustellen — schreiben: "8 Prozent der Befragten **äußerten** die Ansicht, dass...", denn ob sie wirklich dieser Ansicht **sind**, weiß kein Mensch (wie Kommentator Liechtenstein oben schon richtig anmerkte). Wo aber solche Präzision fehlt, ist der Konjunktiv immhin ein Rettungsring.